WorkflowCore: Steps not triggered in a simple workflow implementation
I'm using the WorkflowCore package to implement a simple document status workflow in a .NET Core application. I've defined a workflow that listens for document status change events and executes steps based on the document's current status. However, the steps are not being triggered as expected.
    public class DocumentWorkflow : IWorkflow<Document>
    {
        public string Id => "DocumentWorkflow";
        public int Version => 1;

        public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder<Document> builder)
        {
            builder
                .StartWith(context => ExecutionResult.Next())
                .WaitFor("DocumentStatusChange", (data, context) => context.Workflow.Id, data => DateTime.Now)
                    .Output(data => data.Status, step => (DocumentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(DocumentStatus), step.EventData.ToString()))
                .When(data => data.Status == DocumentStatus.Unread)
                    .Do(then => then
                        .StartWith<UnreadToInProgressStep>()
                            .Input(step => step.Document, data => data))
                .When(data => data.Status == DocumentStatus.InProgress)
                    .Do(then => then
                        .StartWith<InProgressToDoneStep>()
                            .Input(step => step.Document, data => data))
                .When(data => data.Status == DocumentStatus.Deny)
                    .Do(then => then
                        .StartWith<AnyToDenyStep>()
                            .Input(step => step.Document, data => data));
        }
    }

And here is workflow steps :
  public class UnreadToInProgressStep : StepBody
  {
      public Document Document { get; set; }

      public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
      {
          if (Document.Status == DocumentStatus.Unread)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Processing Unread to In Progress...");
              Document.Status = DocumentStatus.InProgress;
              Console.WriteLine($"Document '{Document.Title}' status changed to: {Document.Status}");
          }
          return ExecutionResult.Next();
      }
  }

  public class InProgressToDoneStep : StepBody
  {
      public Document Document { get; set; }

      public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
      {
          if (Document.Status == DocumentStatus.InProgress)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Processing In Progress to Done...");
              Document.Status = DocumentStatus.Done;
              Console.WriteLine($"Document '{Document.Title}' status changed to: {Document.Status}");
          }
          return ExecutionResult.Next();
      }
  }

  public class AnyToDenyStep : StepBody
  {
      public Document Document { get; set; }

      public override ExecutionResult Run(IStepExecutionContext context)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Processing to Deny...");
          Document.Status = DocumentStatus.Deny;
          Console.WriteLine($"Document '{Document.Title}' status changed to: {Document.Status}");
          return ExecutionResult.Next();
      }
  }

Configuration :
    private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddLogging();
        services.AddWorkflow(cfg => cfg.UsePersistence(sp=> new MemoryPersistenceProvider()));

        services.AddTransient<IWorkflow<Document>, DocumentWorkflow>();
        services.AddTransient<UnreadToInProgressStep>();
        services.AddTransient<InProgressToDoneStep>();
        services.AddTransient<AnyToDenyStep>();

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        return serviceProvider;
    }

And main method :
   IServiceProvider serviceProvider = ConfigureServices();

   // Start the workflow host
   var host = serviceProvider.GetService<IWorkflowHost>();
   host.RegisterWorkflow<DocumentWorkflow, Document>();
   host.Start();

   // Create initial document
   var document = new Document
   {
       Title = "Sample Document",
       Status = DocumentStatus.Unread
   };

   // Start the workflow
   var workflowId = host.StartWorkflow("DocumentWorkflow", 1, document).Result;

   // Simulate status changes and publish events
   PublishStatusChange(host, workflowId, document, DocumentStatus.InProgress);
   PublishStatusChange(host, workflowId, document, DocumentStatus.Done);
   PublishStatusChange(host, workflowId, document, DocumentStatus.Deny);

   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
   Console.ReadKey();

   host.Stop();

    private static void PublishStatusChange(IWorkflowHost host, string workflowId, Document document, DocumentStatus newStatus)
    {
        document.Status = newStatus;
        Console.WriteLine($"Document status changed to: {document.Status}");
        host.PublishEvent("DocumentStatusChange", workflowId, document.Status.ToString()).Wait();
    }

Workflow Not Executing Steps: When I change the document status and publish an event, I expect the corresponding steps (like UnreadToInProgressStep) to be executed. However, nothing happens, and the workflow doesn't seem to trigger these steps.
No Errors: There are no error messages or exceptions being thrown, and the workflow ID is generated correctly.
Debugging: I tried adding Console.WriteLine statements inside each step to debug, but these are not being hit, which suggests that the steps are not being called at all.
